# Does the word "androgynous" mean something derogatory?

Tags: meaning, offensive-language

What is the context in which the word "androgynous" can be used so as not to be derogatory?

Comment: It's entirely a matter of opinion. Some people (males *and* females) find androgyny attractive, others don't. [Kate Moss sports chic androgynous outfit,](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3246149/Kate-Moss-rocks-chic-androgynous-outfit-joins-leggy-mini-skirt-clad-Cara-Delevingne-Mango-store-opening-Milan.html) for example.

Comment: In my opinion, this may sound derogatory and the query is actually whether "androgyny" is used in literature for human beings and your comment/link answered it.

Comment: This is an etiquette  (and possobly psychology) question, not one about English grammar, and as such is off topic for EL&U. I will say that a great number of people, due to their own gender fixations, would take great umbrage at being called 'androgynous', and through [transference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transference) regard application of 'androgynous' to anything as derogatory.

Comment: @Spencer But in so far as it involves the sense in which a word is used, whatever else it might be, it is clearly a language issue. But if *androgynous* is derogatory, what is the polite term?

Comment: [Li Yu Chun, who is known for her boyish, androgynous looks, said she was surprised to be chosen as a L'Oreal ambassador since she represents a different look than some of their other representatives,](http://www.sandiegouniontribune.com/sdut-seen-and-heard-in-cannes-2013may26-story.html) according to the *San Diego Union Tribune*. And no doubt millions of Chinese (not to mention the rest of the world) find [Li Yuchun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Yuchun) attractive - that's presumably why L'Oreal *chose* her.

Comment: In a scientific register (though interestingly, [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/androgynous) carries the broader sense << 2. Being neither distinguishably masculine nor feminine, as in dress, appearance, or behavior. >> while Collins doesn't).

Comment: @SRS do you want to refer to a person? a thing? There is the term '[unisex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unisex)' but you do not apply it to people.

Comment: These kinds of questions show that a dictionary has not been used....

Comment: FumbleFingers A search for synonyms gave the following: *bisexualstar, cross-sexualstar, epicenestar, hermaphroditestar, trans-sexualstar, unisexual*. None of them sound especially *chic* to me, and nor does *androgynous*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it certainly shouldn't be considered derogatory in the case of people born with a rare condition and who were classified/labeled medically as hermaphrodites, that is having both male and female sex organs or other sexual characteristics. Many, though not all, of these people display androgynous features or characteristics as distinct from others who might have some of their male and/or female sexual organs located within the body, not outwardly visible. Nowadays such people are more likely to be referred to as having an intersex condition or status. Some display androgynous features while other intersex people look male or female as the case may be.